# Redirect subdomain to folder in nginx version 1.1.19 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, web-server

I inherited a web server and I'm trying to set up a subdomain.  We have other subdomains on the same server and they're working fine, but when I put the exact same info into the configuration file, it doesn't work.  All it does is redirect me to www.

The configuration I'm plagiarizing looks like this:

```
server {
    server_name sub1.example.com;
    root /mnt/webfiles/Web/sub1;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/sub1.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/sub1.error.log;
    include /etc/nginx/custom/common.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/custom/vhost-php.conf;
}
```

Works great. Users go to http://sub1.example.com and they see all the files in /mnt/webfiles/Web/sub1.

I set up a new subdomain, and users are immediately bounced to www.example.com

```
server {
    server_name sub2.example.com;

    root /mnt/webfiles/Web/sub2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/sub2.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/sub2.error.log;
    include /etc/nginx/custom/common.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/custom/vhost-php.conf;
}
```

I really don't care if users get redirected to www.example.com/sub2 or if their browser still shows sub2.domain.com.  Whatever works.

I found this elsewhere but it didn't work (still bounces me to www):

```
server {
  server_name sub2.example.com;
  return 301 "http://example.com/sub2${uri}";
}
```

the /sub2 folder exists and has an index.php page in it.  What am I missing?

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

You most likely made the new configuration file in `/etc/sites-available` directory, and didn't make a symbolic link to `/etc/sites-enabled` directory. Therefore the configuration file is not loaded by nginx, and it uses the default virtual host which makes the redirect.